# Install PHP 5.3 on Centos 6

Tags: php, centos, yum

I am setting up a staging server using CentOS and need to install PHP 5.3 to mirror my production server. Using the standard `yum install php` I'm sure will give me 5.4 - I've had a look and can't figure out how to specify a version number to install. Can anyone advise? Many thanks.

Comment: What repositories are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To specify a version you do:

```
yum install php-5.3.3-14
```

This assumes that php-5.3.3-14 is available in the repos that your staging server. To see available php versions do:

```
yum list php
```

or `yum search php` and peruse the list it gives you. I am on a CentOS6 box right now and it comes with php-5.3.3-14.

I am assuming you are on Fedora since you mention php 5.4. Would it not be more advisable if you build your staging server with the same OS and repo sources as your production?

I think folks will be able to help you more if you state what OS versions and packages and what repositories are available to your production server. I might be wrong but i think that php rpms must also match the apache they are built for as a module.